# Testing for the existence of dependencies in time series

Tags: time-series, independence

What methods exist to test for the existence of any sort of dependence in a time series?  This is in contrast to something like auto-correlation, which tests for a particular type of dependency.  Is there something that can say if dependencies exist, in general, without necessarily determining what kind?

I have **heard of** and experimented with something called a "differential spectrum test", which states that the histogrammed *changes* in the time series should be symmetric about zero if the series of changes is independent.  (i.e. histogram the set of $x_{t+1} - x_{t}$ and it should be symmetric about zero).  If anyone has a reference for this test, I would appreciate it.

Update:

The comments suggest that failing a white noise test would indicate that some sort of dependencies exist.  True?  I guess it must depend on the test.  Here are some I have found.. any comments on their applicability here?

[Bartlett and Q Tests](http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~jnewton/stat626/topics/topics/topic13.pdf)

[Welch's Method](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Welch_s_Method.html)

[Method of Perez et. al.](http://www.uv.es/asepuma/XV/comunica/303.pdf)

[Method of Lobato and Velasco](http://repec.org/esLATM04/up.4121.1081794204.pdf)

Comment: What kind of "dependence" are you looking for specifically?  After all, we could take a series $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ that satisfies your "differential spectrum test" and set $x_{n+j}=x_j+x_n-x_1$, $j=1,\ldots,n$.  This series of $2n$ values would satisfy the test--the histogram is almost the same, with a slightly higher peak at $0$--but contains a very strong dependence indeed (half the values are completely determined by the other half)!  Note, too, that your test is *not* a test of independence: it is merely a test of symmetry of first differences, which is much weaker than independence.

Comment: @whuber Ideally, the test would conclude that the time series is not independent.  In other words, a completely general test that could tell us when some sort of dependency exists, but not necessarily the kind of dependence.

Comment: So why are you actually not looking for the test on independence, with the alternative that some kind of dependence exists? Any (_weak_ just zero mean, constant variance, uncorrelated OR _strong_ + identically distributed) _white noise tests_ are welcome here.

Comment: @DmitrijCelov Yes, failing a (strong) test for independence would fit the bill.  Can you suggest anything?  Is [Welch's Method](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Welch_s_Method.html) applicable?